# OOP and MySQL Table Joins

Tags: mysql, oop

Is it 'allowed' to use table joins while OOP? Or is this unpleasant code?

I couldn't find any helpful article in the internet.

If it is, how would one implement it?

Comment: What does object-oriented programming have to do with relational databases?

Comment: OOP is for modeling system behaviour. Objects encapsulate data. Joins are used to combine sets of data. There's no reason we can't use both, but OOP and relational algebra are separate disciplines, don't get them mixed up.